# Recursive launchfile call falling to execute

Tags: ros2, ros2-launch

I'm working on a launchfile that recursively calls itself N times, depending on a parameter. However whenever I try to run it no nodes are initialized, could you help me find the error ? Thanks a lot

```
def generate_launch_description():


        agents_launch_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'agents',
            default_value='3'
        )

        sim_config = join(get_package_share_directory('mrs_simulator'),
                        'config', 'sim_config.yaml')

        com_config = join(get_package_share_directory('mrs_simulator'),
                        'config', 'com_config.yaml')

        localisation_node = Node(
            package='mrs_ziloc',
            executable='mrs_ziloc_node',
            name=["agent",LaunchConfiguration('agents'),"_z_localisation"],
            parameters=[sim_config, com_config], 
            arguments=[LaunchConfiguration('agents'),'/']
        )

        recursive_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
            
            PathJoinSubstitution([
                    FindPackageShare('mrs_simulator'),
                    'launch',
                    'individual_agent.launch.py'
                ]),
            launch_arguments={
                'agents':PythonExpression([LaunchConfiguration('agents'),  '-1'])
            }.items(), 
            condition = IfCondition(PythonExpression(['(',LaunchConfiguration('agents'),  '-1)', '> 0']))
        )

        return LaunchDescription([
            agents_launch_arg,
            recursive_launch,
            localisation_node
        ])
```

Comment: If someone faces a similar issue you can just us a regular for loop to stack N nodes in a list and modify their parameters with regular python string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

No idea why this does not work, but if the number of agents is given you can just write a Python loop to repeat things.
If the number of agents is not known and should be a launch arguments, you can have a look at the [Opaque Function idiom](https://discourse.ros.org/t/simplifying-launch-argument-declaration-and-initialization-in-launch-files/24204).

Alternatively, you may use the [simple_launch](https://github.com/oKermorgant/simple_launch#opaquefunction-with-implicit-performcontext) package (I am the author) to easily use the opaque function.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try